# How can I get the original pixels that lead to the decision in CNN?

Tags: python, cnn, image-classification, computer-vision

I work on medical images and I want to locate the most relevant regions of the image based on deep learning spatially CNN. So I feed my data into VGG16 architecture and get the features maps. Now I want to figure how can I go back from the feature maps in the original image to recover the positions of areas? How can it be done?
Most of what I found is related to a detection object, like RCNN, but that is not what I'm searching for. I need to recover all the areas that CNN pay attention to, not only that depends on one class.

Comment: Hi Omri, please make your problem more descriptive. Please read [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before moving further.

Comment: Provide the architecture of the network so can understand what you asking exactly ...

Comment: We can superimpose them, check out CAM's